# How to choose between linear or nonlinear mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, model-selection, linear, nonlinear

I don't really understand when it come to mixed model,
how do you know when to use linear or nonlinear model?

For example, when using R function `lmer` to build linear mixed model,
my model may look like this:

```
lmer( Y ~ X1 + X2 + X1*X2 + (1|Z) )
```

where $Y$ is the response (from a repeated measured data), $X_1$ and $X_2$ are fixed effects and $Z$ is the random effect.

Does this means when you pick these effects up to see their relation separately, like `Y~X1` and `Y~X2`, both has to be linear so than you can use linear mixed model?

What if `Y~X1` is nonlinear and `Y~X2` is linear? Should I use nonlinear mixed model when this is the case?

Comment: what is the last term i.e.1/Z .  and how do we compute Z  here . What is Z ? Just for my understanding  your model. ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly about whether the relationships between Y and the various X are linear or not; a linear model is one that is linear in the *parameters* (just like the case with nonmixed models). So

$Y = a + b_1X_1 + b_2X_2^2 + b_3X_3$

is linear, but if there are parameters (b) in the exponents, it is not.

Usually, nonlinear mixed models are used when Y is not continuous. They are used for the mixed versions of logistic regression, count regression and so on.

Comment: Logistic regression (which is a generalized linear model) is usually considered to be a linear model and not a "nonlinear model".

Comment: Yes, but to do a mixed logistic model, you need to use (in SAS) GLIMMIX or NLMIXED.  The terminology is very confusing. Logistic regression is linear if you take the logit as the DV.  It is not linear in the original DV.

Comment: I agree that the terminology is confusing. But mixed logistic is a *generalied linear mixed model* (GLMM) and in my experience people usually do *not* call it "nonlinear".

Comment: Right, but in R, there is the nlme package, where the N stands for nonlinear.  In SAS you can't use MIXED (which is for linear). Anyway, we agree on the facts, it's just the terms that are confusing!  I, for one, don't like the use of "mixed" because "fixed" and "random" also get confusing.  Plus there's the general linear model and the generalized linear model!  Oy vey!

Comment: @amoeba, I would say that GLiMs are linear in a transformed space, but not in their 'native' space. I think the terminology here is rather fraught.

Answer (score 0):

Linear mixed-effects model presumes that there are  fixed -effeets and random effect. lmer does imply that Y tends to be linearly related with X1 as well as X2. In case X1 is nolnlinearly related to Y and X2 is linearily related to Y,  non-linear mixed model is not recommended.  You can log-tranform X1 the  variable which is non-linearly related to Y and  use lmer.